# Keras mystery: Training and Validation accuracy flat-lining, yet predictions look ok

Tags: python, keras

I have set up a very simple Keras model with a couple of Dense layers, and I am trying to 'predict' the return on a single stock using the returns on 3 other stocks. For now I am not bothering with offsetting dates, since I am just trying to get the model to run properly.
I have initially simplified the targets in both the training/validation set and the test set, by replacing the actual returns with a 1 for positive return and a 0 for negative return.
The relevant code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Daily returns BAC-JPM-UBS-WFC.csv')

X = df[['JPM', 'UBS', 'WFC']]
y = df[['BAC']]


# Replace target returns with 1 for positive return, 0 for negative return
y.loc[y["BAC"] >= 0, "BAC"] = 1
y.loc[y["BAC"] < 0, "BAC"] = 0


# Import testing dataset
df_test = pd.read_csv('Daily returns_X_test BAC-JPM-UBS-WFC.csv')
X_test = df_test[['JPM', 'UBS', 'WFC']]
y_test = df_test[['BAC']]
y_test.loc[y_test["BAC"] >= 0, "BAC"] = 1
y_test.loc[y_test["BAC"] < 0, "BAC"] = 0


# Model specification
no_of_inputs = len(X. columns)
input_layer = Input(shape=(no_of_inputs), dtype='float32')
dense1 = Dense(8, activation='linear')(input_layer)
dense2 = Dense(8, activation='linear')(dense1)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(dense2)


# Model instantiation and dataset fit
epochs = 30
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
optimzer = keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimzer, metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
H = model.fit(x=X, y=y, validation_split=0.3, batch_size=5, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, shuffle=True)  

# Model prediction
predictions = model.predict(x=X_test, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
```

When I run the code I get the following for Training and Validation losses:
[image]

I get this for Training and Validation accuracy:
[image]

And I get this when I plot y_test vs predictions:
[image]

This looks reasonable, but what I really wanted to do was use the actual return values from the train/val and the test sets as targets, instead of the simplified binary 1 and 0.
So when I remove:

```
y.loc[y["BAC"] >= 0, "BAC"] = 1
y.loc[y["BAC"] < 0, "BAC"] = 0
```

and:

```
y.loc[y["BAC"] >= 0, "BAC"] = 1
y.loc[y["BAC"] < 0, "BAC"] = 0
```

from the code, and just use the actual return values, I get the following results.

[image]
[image]
[image]

While the Training and Validation losses look ok, although a bit sluggish, the Accuracy charts are basically 'flat-lining', and yet the y_test vs predictions chart looks exactly the way I would excpect.

I have tried playing around with the learning rate, picking different optimisers, and swapping out 'linear' for 'relu' in the Dense layers, but this has had no impact on the result.
I just can't work out why the training and validation accuracy a 'flat-lining' on my chart.
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric, while you have a regression problem. You always have to think if your metrics are appropriate for your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Can Accuracy not be set to somehow capture deviation from from y_test in a regression setup?  Or is there a different metric I can use? @ Dr. Snoopy

Comment: You would have to create your own metrics, accuracy as you are using it is classification only. And different metrics? For what purpose? You have not said why you need additional metrics.

Comment: I would just like to be able to observe the model evolve as it goes through the speficied number of epochs - just like I can with the training and validation losses.

Comment: You can do that with the loss (it is also a metric in concept), as I originally said you need to select metrics based in your specific problem, not just use metrics for no reason.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I just added a new chart to the OP with a new accurat metric - and a new mystery......